# Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255) returns -1

Tags: android, colors, argb

I am trying to change the alpha of a `TextPaint` property and when I set `Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)` on that property it returns `-1` why is this happening?

```
 public void updatePaint() {
    int red = Color.red(Color.WHITE);
    int green = Color.green(Color.WHITE);
    int blue = Color.blue(Color.WHITE);
    int alpha = Color.alpha(Color.WHITE);

    int color = Color.argb((int) (alpha * mAlpha), red, green, blue);

    textPaint.setColor(color);
}
```

The property `mAlpha` changes from 0.0-1.0

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what it should be.

Solid white is `0xFFFFFFFF` in hexadecimal, which is `-1` in decimal.

For confirmation, check the value of `Color.WHITE`.